# How to stack ng-repeat list elements vertically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ul class="row">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Problem: the items are stacked horizontally:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

But I'd like them to stack vertically:

```
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Question: how?

Comment: I think there is only one way You can do it.. by changing the order of `items`. You can do it by custom filter or in controller.

Comment: It's not related to js/angular, imo. I think, you could try to use flexbox, or just write js function (angular filter) that changes collection order to satisfy your requirements.